# How to linking two different version of third-party library in qt plugin in system?

Tags: c++, qt5, ld

I'm developing a QT(c++) plugin applicaton. I build my plugins into dynamic libraries. So basically, a specific plugin may depend on other third-party libraries.

Here is my problem, some plugins will use the same third-party libraries, suchlike opencv or protobuf. But, they may depend on different version of that library. This may cause unexpected behaviors when loading plugins or running appliction.

My question is how to solve this problem in a suitable way?

Comment: On which platform?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Linux. More specifically, my device is ubuntu 18.04 amd-64

Comment: make sure the libraries have different sonames and load the plugin using the appropriate flags

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks. Actually, I meet a problem in real. And I have made a minimal program, how ever it is too large and complicated(although I have made my most to extract it from my project). I don't konw how to put it here.